# Android - get name and quantity of each product in same line

Tags: java, android, email, android-edittext, custom-lists

I want to send an email with products and product names that user added to their cart.On clicking order button, an email is send with the product details in cart.I am getting product name and quantity as bundle from another activity.I am receiving mail body as

**products :[product1,product2 ]**

**quantity :2,3**

But what I need is

**products: product1-2 ,product2-3.**

This is how I am accesing values for email

**emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"products:"+productnames+"\n"+"quantity:"+prqty);**

Comment: posting the whole project doesn't explain your problem any better!!! Why can't you be more specific? `But what I need is products: product1-2 ,product2-3` doesn't explain what you want to achieve

Comment: @Leo I have added some more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add sequential the information coz you recieve now as an arraylist of products.

> count = 0 // this will u to know the product where u are.
>
> for (productname: products) {
>
> ```
> emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"productname:"+productnames+"\n"+"quantity:"+prqty[count]);
> ```
>
> count++
> }